# How can I make a custom field visible with the REST API (NOT THE WEB UI)?

Tags: rest-api, api, metadata-api, tooling-api

How can I make a custom field visible with the REST API (NOT THE WEB UI)?  Preferably when I create the custom field.

Currently I create a field like this,

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://[company]-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [token]' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{ 
     "FullName": "Account.Class__c",     
   "Metadata": { 
         "label": "Class",
      "description": "Class Field", 
      "required": false, 
      "externalId": false, 
      "type": "Text", 
      "length": 32 
   }
}'
```

However I am unable to use this field in other API calls until it is "visible", that is until it has the PermissionsEdit and PermissionsRead entries set to true for each profile in the FieldPermissions table.

```
SELECT Field, Id, ParentId, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead, SobjectType, SystemModstamp FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field = 'Account.Class__c'
```

How can I make this happen with the REST API?  What is the ParentId in this table?  Seems like I need to make entries here.

Comment: Metadata API = SOAP. There's a popular Apex wrapper: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: That is really not helpful, I'm looking for a response like, POST this XML to this endpoint...

Comment: Turns out setting required to true will set the visibility also, so this kinda works but just need to make sure when updating an count you always post this field.